# I have a table where i need to group and count 2 columns within a certain date range

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have the following table in MSaccess and i need to group by joining 2 columns, and give a count of the duplicated, within a certain date/time range, and if possible type and city, but that isn't mandatory.

```
LocationX LocationY DateTimeStamp,      City      Type
100       150       08/01/2013 8:59:44  Brisbane  RadioJob
101       155       08/01/2013 9:56:01  Brisbane  RadioJob
100       150       08/01/2013 8:49:39  Brisbane  RadioJob
103       150       08/01/2013 8:55:13  Brisbane  RadioJob
```

i need to join column 0 and column 1 together and do a count, but only selecting locations within a certain time range.

so for example, if i chose between 08/01/2013 8:49:00 and 08/01/2013 8:59:59 I should get the following table:

```
LocationX LocationY CountOfLocation  City      Type
100       150       2                Brisbane  RadioJob
103       150       1                Brisbane  RadioJob
```

As it stands ive written 2 queries in MSaccess with design view to get this to work, but i would like to try and learn how to do this in one SQL statement.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT LocationX, LocationY, City, Type, COUNT(*) CountOfLocation  
FROM   tableName
WHERE  DateTimeStamp BETWEEN '2013-08-01 8:49:00' AND '2013-08-01 8:59:59'
GROUP  BY LocationX, LocationY, City, Type
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03435/5)

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT LocationX, LocationY, City, Type, COUNT(*) AS CountOfLocation  
FROM   tableName
WHERE  DateTimeStamp BETWEEN #2013-08-01 08:49:00# AND #2013-08-01 08:59:59#
GROUP  BY LocationX, LocationY, City, Type
```

Comment: Due to a couple of syntax errors, this will not run in MS Access, ErikE's answer will.

Comment: @MattDonnan the question wasn't tag as `ms access` before it has been accepted.

Comment: @JW. Ah I see, always a pain when that happens, if you tweak it for Access then I'll upvote.

Comment: @MattDonnan in `MS Access`, you need to use `#` instead of single \quotes for dates.

Comment: And the **AS** keyword for aliasing `Count(*)`, I've amended that one and upvoted : )

Comment: @MattDonnan i think `AS` is optional. `:D`

Comment: @JW. If only it were, Access is terribly picky ^_^

Comment: Look at the first post. It said "MSaccess". And frankly I feel kind of cheated that a wrong answer that wouldn't even run in the clearly stated DBMS got "help" to get upvoted over a correct answer given a mere 17 seconds later... :P

Comment: @Matt Check the first post... Access was there in the text which is how I knew to tag it.

Comment: @ErikE if this answer feels you cheated, nevermind, i'll deleted this if the OP unaccept this answer.

Comment: Naw JW it's ok. Just my life seemingly appearing in effigy. :) I'm having lack-of-recognition issues obviously!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
   L.LocationX,
   L.LocationY,
   Count(*) AS CountOfLocation,
   L.City,
   L.Type
FROM
   Locations L
WHERE
   DateTimeStamp >= #08/01/2013 08:49:00#
   AND DateTimeStamp < #08/01/2013 09:00:00#
GROUP BY
   L.LocationX,
   L.LocationY,
   L.City,
   L.Type;
```

I'd like to point out that my change from using `BETWEEN` to inequalities was quite deliberate. The reason is that using `BETWEEN` requires that the underlying date data type has a particular resolution or granularity (here, seconds). But let's say your database grows and gets upsized to SQL Server some day. After addressing obvious issues like date literals, there's going to be lurking a nasty little gotcha in a conversion to the `datetime` data type: suddenly values between seconds will be possible and data will be improperly excluded.

My professional advice is to begin consistently using the syntax as show in my query in ALL your database queries: an inclusive start time and exclusive end time. Consider that learning best-practice habits will serve you well in any DBMS...

Also, while it's true that the date literal in Access requires the `#` wrapper, you have the option of choosing SQL-Server compatible syntax at the database level which then works with `'`. I actually recommend this switch as the syntax is less quirky, and in the upsizing scenario will be a gigantic blessing due to having far, far less work to do. But if you change now, your existing queries will all have to be fixed immediately.